# How can I generate number from 0 to 100 using 'react-select'?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I'm using react and how can I create a dropdown that display number from 0 to 100% ?

My Dropdown:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select';
import Tag from './Tag'

export default function Dropdown({ className, options, styleSelect, defaultValue}) {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(defaultValue);     

    return (
        <>
            {selected ?
                <Tag selected={selected} setSelected={setSelected} styleSelect={styleSelect} />
                :
                <Select className={className} value={selected} onChange={setSelected} options={options}/>
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

If it wasn't so long I would do :

```
const PERCENTAGE = [
        { label: '0', value: '0' },
        ...
    ]
```

and do `<CustomDropdown options={PERCENTAGE}/>`

Or I was thinking of using jquery but it's not working

Comment: You can create the `PERCENTAGE` array with a for loop. However, a select seems like poor UX. It would be better to use a input field that the user can type the number in.

Comment: But with select the user will be able to enter also his own value in addition to select the value from the dropdown

Comment: You can achieve the PERCENTAGE array by running a for loop like -
```const PERCENTAGES = [...new Array(101)].map((each, index) => ({ label: index, value: index });```
However, this would be poor UX. You can probably try `<input type="range">`, if you haven't explored already.

Comment: @himayan Is there a way to  do `const PERCENTAGES = [...new Array(101)].map((each, index) => ({ label: index, value: index });` but with a gap of 20 (0, 20,40,60,80,100) ?

Comment: Yes, you can do `const PERCENTAGES = [...new Array(6)].map((each, index) => ({ label: (index * 20), value: (index * 20) });`

Comment: Great!! Let me create an answer for it. Users would have an easier time if there is an accepted answer, instead of combing through the comments. @Zokulko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the PERCENTAGE array by mapping an array of 101 elements like -

```js
const PERCENTAGES = [...new Array(101)]
  .map((each, index) => ({ label: index, value: index });
```

However, this would be poor UX. You can probably try `<input type="range">`, if you haven't explored already.

**EDIT** -

If you need to generate one with a gap of 20, then you can create an array of 6 and map them by multiplying a factor of 20 -

```js
const PERCENTAGES = [...new Array(6)]
   .map((each, index) => {
      const value = index * 20;
      return ({
        label: value,
        value,
      })
   });
```